# fullCalendar dynamic eventClick behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar with 2 JSON feeds for my event sources. I'm using eventClick to open a modal window when an event is clicked. However, I only need the modal windows for the first event source (json-events.php). I would like for all events from the second source (json-paidstaff.php) to just be static boxes with no eventClick function. Is there any way to specify eventClick for only one source?

My js currently

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

editable: false,
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
eventSources: [
    // your event source
    {
        url: 'json-events.php?uid=$bbuserinfo[userid]'
    },

    // any other sources...
    {
        url: 'json-paidstaff.php?uid=$bbuserinfo[userid]',
        color: 'black', // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'white' // a non-ajax option
    }

],

eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.namescreds);
},

loading: function (bool) {
    if (bool) $.blockUI();
    else $.unblockUI();
},

eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.blockUI();
    Boxy.load('ajax.php?uid=$bbuserinfo[userid]&id=' + calEvent.id, {
        modal: true,
        closeable: true,
        afterShow: ($.unblockUI())
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As given in the documentation you can have your own non-standard fields, where we can any arbitrary information, in our case we can store where the event belongs to.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [{
        "id": 1,
            "title": "Hello World",
            "start": "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 09:00:00",
            "end": "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 10:00:00",
        "belongsto" : "list 1"

    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "title": "Good Afternoon",
            "start": "Wed, 23 Jan 2014 13:00:00",
            "end": "Wed, 23 Jan 2014 17:00:00",
        "belongsto" : "list 2"
    }],
     eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
         alert(calEvent.belongsto);
         if(calEvent.belongsto === "list 1") {
               //do something.
         }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LVLMC/1/)**